# Difference between a router and an actor

Tags: akka

I am learning akka but I am unable to find any difference between router and actor.Router is used to redefine paths between senders and receivers and actor serves a dedicated work. Please let me know if there is any difference between both structurally (in terms of actor components).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of Akka Routers is to provide a mechanism for executing messages in parallel. Messages can be sent via a router to efficiently ***route*** them to destination actors aka its ***routees*** (the ones serving a dedicated work). Thus, it is not only about redefining paths.

In terms of internal structure, when it comes to a router actor (you can also define a [standalone router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html#A_Simple_Router)) , the **message delivery** is optimized:

- messages are not enqueued in the router actor’s mailbox
- messages are sent directly to a routee

Another key difference is the fact that the router actor forwards messages to its routees without changing the original sender. Hence, when you write:

```scala
class TaskEngine extends Actor {
  val routeePaths: List[String] = ...
  val router: ActorRef = system.actorOf(RoundRobinGroup(paths).props(), "coffee-house-group")

  def receive = {
    case msg => router ! msg
  }
}
```

becomes equivalent to the following in a normal actor.

```scala
class BasicActor(workerActor: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case msg => workerActor forward msg
  }
}
```

I hope this answers to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but please let me know from where i can learn akka as a beginner

Comment: Great answer, thanks. One more question however, what is the exact difference between a standalone router and a self-contained router actor like the one you use in your example? I read the documentation but it is still unclear to me. Thanks in advance